# Calculations of factorials

Tags: programming-languages

Working over a problem connected with analytic number theory, I want to make some simple computer experiments in order to examine some theoretical conjectures. The algorithms are very simple: they contain standard arithmetic operations and factorials, but I would like to find values depending on a parameter. For instance, if I understand correctly, the problem with such calculations at [WolframAlpha service](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) is that I cannot write an expression depending on a parameter and then change the value of the parameter by typing it only once. But that is what I need. I am new in programming, long ago I used some old languages like Algol, but I am not aware of the modern situation with simple computer experiments. So, my goal is to calculate some simple expressions for multiple values of a parameter, preferably with installing some simple software or by using an online machinery. How could this be done?

Assuming that my question can be perceived as off topic, if so, I would much appreciate any further recommendations before closing.

Comment: [Parameter (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_\(computer_programming\))

Comment: Defining a function that takes an argument can be done in virtually any non-esoteric language (including Algol), so this isn't a very specific requirement. Just pick any language you want. If you want you can look up [the factorial function on Rosetta Code](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Factorial) to compare how it can be implemented in different languages.

Comment: @sepp2k I don't know what language I may want, this is what I ask. I want the language and the compiler to be as simple as possible to learn and to install.

Comment: That's entirely subjective. Just look at the page I've linked and pick the one that looks the most simple to you. Maybe cross-reference it with a list of the 20-or-so most popular programming languages first to cut down the list of options to something manageable.

Comment: @sepp2k Maybe... Something like WolframAlpha but allowing parameters would be best for me, however, if such option does not exist, I will check the page. Many thanks!